# IE9 JQuery Function Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue calling a function using jquery in IE9. This works in Chrome/Firefox just fine. JQuery is version 1.10.2

Dashboad.aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

dashboard.js

```
$.loadAllJson = function () {
...
...
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.loadAllJson();
});
```

$.loadAllJson() is showing up undefined only in IE9.

Comment: I see no reason why `loadAllJson` would be `undefined` based on what you've provided. What debugging have you done?

Comment: I have debugged in IE9 F12 debugger, this also works fine in IE11.

Comment: And the debugger gives no error messages?

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'loadAllJson' 
dashboard.js, line 319 character 5

Comment: Right, I meant other than that. Can you post a full example? Does your HTML have a doctype declaration?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, IE9 sure is anal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was including jquery twice.  I just commented out this code:

```
<script>
//document.write('<script src=js/vendor/' +
//    ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
//    '.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

I think that was included because of Foundation, not sure if its needed or not.
[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/javascript.html)